# Feedback for an honours project on sound design

Tags: honours, project, surrealism

Hi there

I am finishing my dissertation for an Honours project on sound design. I have been a member of this forum for a while now, and my project requires that a sound designer evaluates my work, in order to include some specialized comments in the Evaluation chapter of the dissertation.

The short film is a mixture of realism, hyperrealism and surrealism. It is 20 minutes long, not too lomg! The thing is that I would need to have a chat through Skype, or any other way that let us having a proper conversation, for they will be questions and answers. That would be difficult by email or by posting here.

Maybe it is too much too ask, but I consider the film could be interesting for some of you guys. It is possible that this will happen at the end of next week, as my dissertation is due on the 30th. I would be very grateful if any of you could give me hand (or a pair of ears!) with this.

Thanks for your time and I will be waiting for your responses.

Comment: I'd do it Marco but I'm pretty inexperienced, good luck!

Comment: thanks chris!

I was starting to think I would never get anyone... I will let you know when it's ready, it should be ready more or less in a week today. I will upload it to youtube and we can have a chat on skype, if you have an account. It'll be something quick.

Thanks again! 

Comment: Not a problem you are inexperienced, I have seen your work in your website and some of it it's impressive.. So if you are up for it, let me know this week. 

Thanks chris